# Eslint no-unused-vars rule issue

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, next.js

I am using nextjs to and one of the functionlities is profile view, delete, update on my profile component I have a props with onsuccess function which looks like this

```
type DeleteProfileParams = {
  // 'profile' is defined but never used.eslintno-unused-vars/eslint rule error
  onSuccess?: (profile: Profile) => void
}
```

onsucccessful deletion I execute the onsucess function that is passed from the parent with the result form the api request.
I was thinking to turn off the no-unused-var eslint rule but this might not be the right way to resolve the issue I hope, I was wandering if there is a better way to rsolve this with out turning off no-unused-var on the entire project or for this line specifically.

I tried disabling for that line only, it is working fine for me but I want to know if there is a better way to handle such issues.
// eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
my .eslint.json looks like thi and I am using the latest eslint version

```
{
 "env": {
    "browser": true,
    "es2021": true,
    "node": true
  },
  "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
  "extends": [
    "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended",
    "next/core-web-vitals",
    "eslint:recommended",
    "plugin:react/jsx-runtime",
    "plugin:react/jsx-runtime",
    "prettier"
  ],
  "globals": {
    "React": "readonly"
  },
  "rules": {
    "@typescript-eslint/no-var-requires": "off"
  },
  "overrides": [
    {
      "files": [
        "*.test.{ts,tsx}",
        "src/testing/**/*.{ts,tsx}"
      ],
      "globals": {
        "it": "readonly",
        "describe": "readonly"
      },
      "rules": {
        "@typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any": "off",
        "@typescript-eslint/ban-ts-comment": "off"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Yes and No, The error can be easily solved by turning off the rule, that is what I found everywhere Unfortunately Typescript is not smart enough to identify it is just type definition, I thought it might be a bad idea to turn off the rule but it seems it is the only way.

Comment: If you think it's a bad idea to turn off the rule, why not follow the suggestion in the duplicate and use `@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars` instead which does work correct;y with TS types?

Comment: I previously set the rule incorrectly. I should set the @typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars rule to error and turn off the original eslint no-unused-vars rule. This will ensure that TypeScript and ESLint are both aware of the type definitions. Thank you for pointing that out.